# Database connection is opened by creating object or using getwritabledatabase

Tags: android, android-sqlite

My application has 7 activities and all are highly dependent on database and each activity when accessed will query database a lot.

For this issue I have created a singleton database object for the database class and for every operation I am calling below statement.

```
Database.getInstance(c1).getWritableDatabase()
```

for inserts, selects and deletes I am using like below

```
-- insert Database.getInstance(c1).getWritableDatabase().insert
-- select Database.getInstance(c1).getWritableDatabase().rawquery
-- delete Database.getInstance(c1).getWritableDatabase().rawquery
```

I am using this way because by this only one object is used in whole application and multiple objects won't be created.

But when searching the web, I learned that **getWritableDatabase()** will open a connection to database. Now I am confused whether object to database class will open a connection or calling **getwritabledatabase** will open a connection.

I am worrying because I feel I am creating too many connections unknowingly.

### Edit

I have tried to create a writable database object as below in every activity and use that object in that actovity but it returned me database locked exception hence I was forced to use the `Database.getInstance(c1).getWritableDatabase()` for every db operation

I have created as below

```
Sqldatabase sd=Database.getInstance(c1).getWritableDatabase()
```

I am wanting to discover how the database should be opened and where it should be closed to make a application stable and avoid memory leaks. I am am a beginner to Android, and keen to find out if my design is a valid one.

### Edit

Database file

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        private static  String dbname="Director";
        private static int dbversion=1;
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        private Context m1Context;
        private static Database minstance;
        public Database(Context context) {

            super(context, dbname, null, dbversion);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        }

        public synchronized static Database getInstance(Context m1Context){

            if (minstance==null){

            minstance=new Database(m1Context);
            }
            return minstance;


        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            STable st=new StockTable(m1Context);
            BTable bt=new BrokerageTable(m1Context);
            SList sl=new StockList(m1Context);

            db.execSQL(st.stocktable);
            db.execSQL(bt.Brokerage);
            db.execSQL(sl.Create());
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


    }
```

class file:

```
public class SList {

    Context c1;
    Cursor getid;
    StockList(Context mContext){

        c1=mContext;
    }

    **//SQLiteDatabase sd=Database.getInstance(c1).getWritableDatabase();**
    String Ctable;
    //String ,selectIDgetstocks,deletestock;
    public String tablename="Stocklist";
    public String Column1="_id";
    public String Column2="Sname";
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    String getstocks="Select " + Column1 + " as _id, " + Column2 + " From "+ tablename;
    String selectID="Select Max("+  Column1 + ") from " + tablename;
    public String Create(){

        Ctable="Create Table " + tablename + " (" + Column1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " + Column2 + " Text" + ")";

        return Ctable;
    }

    public void insert(int stockid,String name){

        cv.put(Column1, stockid);
        cv.put(Column2, name);
    ++Database.getInstance(c1).getWritableDatabase().insert(tablename,null,cv);++

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe class `Database` is wrapper for `SQLiteOpenHelper`, right? Since you have a singleton, each time you call `getWritableDatabase()` it's utilizing existing connection. The new connection is being called only at the first call. You can open new connection at `onResume` or `onCreate` and close it at `onDestroy` or `onPause`, for example.

From the docs on `getWritableDatabase()`:

Once opened successfully, the database is cached, so you can call this method every time you need to write to the database

Comment: Thanks @nikis for your reply... but my doubt is here as I am unable to create a single getwritabledatabase for a activity.. I am forced to use the `Database.getInstance(c1).getWritableDatabase();` for all db operations saperately.. I want to know whether this will create n connections..Please help me understand

Comment: @Siva nope, it won't. Every call you'll be using the same cahced connection

Comment: Thanks this is a great info for me... one more issue then in this case where should I close the connection? I am planning to close after every statement db operation. is this a correct approach? if not please guide with the correct approach.

Comment: @Siva not a best way in a case if you are working with DB from multiple threads, so it's up to you, depending on the logic of your app

Comment: once again I need your suggestion.. Can you please give me idea why `Sqldatabase sd=Database.getInstanc(c1).getWritableDatabase()` is giving database locked exception when declared at the start of the class **Please see my question for the location where I have declared**. Why it is working when used for individual database operations?

Comment: @Siva it's hard to say without code/logcat. The best practice is to make all ops with DB inside `SQLitOpenHelper` wrapper

Comment: Thanks for your reply nikis... sorry for not giving the code.. in my question edit I have given my database class with sigleton instance and class file where I am using database object. My issue with code between `**` in class file that is giving me error but the code between `++` is fine though there is nothing change with the implementation. Thanks again for your assitance

Comment: I will suggest to put all these `insert`, `update`, etc. methods inside `Database` class and then get `DB` inside them by calling `getWritableDatabase`

Answer (score 2):

You should have a function to open the database, a function to close the database, and other functions to query. Consider the following class:

```
public void openDatabase(){
database = Database.getInstance(c1).getWritableDatabase();
}

public void closeDatabase(){
database.close()
}

public void insert(){
//your insertion code here using database object
}

public String select(){
//your selection code here using database object
}
```

make database class variable. This way you can call `openDatabase()` at first and never have to open again until you close it or instantiate the class for the first time.

Then you can use insert or select as required.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Sujan but my issue here is I have 7 activities and all 7 needs a open database connection, in this case when I use the opendatabase object 7 times it is giving me the `Database locked` exception so I have created singleton my doubt is when I use singleton instance my connection is opened or when I call `getwritabledatabase` my connection is opened?

Comment: According to the documentation, when getWritableDatabase() is called. A new instance of database will be created if it has not been opened recently. If the database is already opened and when we call getWritableDatabase(), then it will try to return the cached object. So, I think the connection is reused instead of creating new one.